# how do i make wonderpush in app message to work for subscribing to web push?

Tags: push-notification, wonderpush

I am having problem on wonderpush. I tried to use the in app functionality to have a custom message for user to subscribe to web push notification but it doesn't work.

I tried modifying the in app sample to use only 1 button to subscribe and it did not work. I see clicks but no one is subscribed to the push notification list.  I have also disabled the native subscribe function.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the automatic subscription prompts like the HTML dialog and the Native Prompt in your Web Settings

[image: Subscription prompts in the web settings]